# What is the use of running JBoss as a Windows Service?

Tags: linux, jboss, windows-services

Is there any advantage in running JBoss as a windows service rather than running from run.bat? I'm running JBoss 4.0.3.

I'm not very familiar with windows so if someone can explain what the use of a Windows Service is or what the Linux equivalent is it will be very helpful.

Comment: Windows services are somewhat an equivalent for Linux daemons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference is when JBoss is started. Using run.bat implies that someone has to log on to launch it, which is not ideal for 24x7 server software. As a Windows Service, JBoss would start automatically as the PC boots, without the need for anyone to log in (or any other human intervention).

Find out more about the benefits (and peculiarities) of Windows Services in the [Windows Services FAQ](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html).

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit from my view, is that jboss will start automatically when the os boots. Otherwise you must log in, at least, and even though it could start as a login start event.